# How to inject a window variable in a storybook?

Tags: reactjs, redux, storybook

I want to add a React component (called `ApplicationForm`) to a [storybook](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook).

The story book is written this way:

```
import { configureStore } from '../store';

const store = configureStore();

storiesOf('application from', module)
  .addDecorator(story => <Provider store={store}>{story()} </Provider>)
  .add('all', () => (
      <ApplicationForm />
  ));
```

The `ApplicationForm` is created with reduxForm. That's why I need to provide a `store` in the `addDecorator` function.

Unfortunately in the `configureStore` function, one of the reducer has a dependency of a global data `window.GLOBAL`.

In the storybook I will see the following error:

```
GLOBAL is not defined
ReferenceError: GLOBAL is not defined
    at initGlobalState (http://localhost:9010/static/preview.bundle.js:86625:3)
```

How can I inject or simulate such global data in the storybook?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I can add a `preview-head.html` file in the `__stories__` directory.

Inside which I have javascript like this:

```
<script>
  var data = { };
  window.GLOBAL = {
    data: data
  };  
 </script>
```

[Documentation](https://storybook.js.org/configurations/add-custom-head-tags/)

Comment: You need to put this file inside `.storybook`  top-level (config) directory and it's important to **restart** storybook's server after the change!

Comment: How this is going to work if I want to use it only for specific story not for all of them?

Comment: Perhaps inside the `.addWithJSX` method

Answer (score 6):

The `window` you're trying to access is the iframe preview.
Try to access the window from outside the iframe, the Storybook `window`.

`window.parent.window.GLOBAL`